# MySQL - Count Space within field (MyCode - Xpress Band - Black)

Tags: mysql

I am working within MYSQL DB and within one of tables I found that I have variation of values for a field.  I need to find out how many fields have extra spaces within them, it use to be user input field where users have inputed various values

```
MyCode - Xpress Band - Black
MyCode -    Xpress Band - Black
MyCode - Xpress Band -    Black
```

Is there way to find records that have more than one space between val1 - val2 - val3 ?

Answer (score 1):

This query will do it for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM yourTableName
WHERE yourFieldName LIKE '% % %'
```

To look specifically for text with space-hyphen-space separators, like in your example, you could use

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM yourTableName
WHERE yourFieldName LIKE '% - % - %'
```

Or, to look for 2+ adjacent spaces,

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM yourTableName
WHERE yourFieldName LIKE '%  %'
```

The `%` is a placeholder meaning "any text", which you can use with the `LIKE` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something special about the values `MyCode` and `Xpress Band` ?  Or is it really just the "extra" space characters before and after a dash that we're concerned with?

This value is "ok" because there is no more than one space before and after each dash?

```
MyCode - Xpress Band - Black
```

And these are the values we want to flag because there's an extra space character?

```
MyCode -    Xpress Band - Black
         ^^^
```

and

```
MyCode - Xpress Band -    Black
                       ^^^
```

If I wanted to find values that had two (or more) space characters before a dash or after a dash, I would do something like this:

```
 SELECT t.various_value
   FROM t 
  WHERE t.various_value LIKE '%  -%'
     OR t.various_value LIKE '%-  %'
```

I'd test that first, and verify the results, before I mucked with adding a `COUNT()` aggregate.

If we're also concerned with other whitespace characters (tab, newline, et al.) then we'd probably want to use a REGEXP regular expression operator instead of `LIKE`.